# RxJava 2 - How to chain asyncronous calls

Tags: java-8, rx-java, observable, rx-android

I've just recently started learning RxJava so don't crucify me if I'm asking a newbie question but I've spend days now in trying to figure this out without any success. I've read almost all the documentation I could find and I followed along most of the tutorials on http://reactivex.io/tutorials.html. I searched StackOverflow and the rest of the Internet high and low but apparently I seem to be the only person on the planet with this problem. Which is odd since essentially it boils down to something every piece of software has to do: Logging in a user.

All the tutorials I found are on applying some functions on a stream creating a new stream which is useful and awesome, don't get me wrong but not really helpful in my case. It also got me thinking ... maybe I go about this all wrong. But I'm stuck so deep now and also following the mantra that "everything is a stream" why should that not be possible?

So here is what I'm trying to do:

1. indicate some form of loading
2. call a `Completable` to perform a login action on some server
3. call a `Single` to perform a create user action on some server which returns a user id for local reference
4. use the result of the `Single` call in the next action and hide loading

Even though I will end up with this on Android I created a basic Java 8 example to outline what I would like to achieve.

This is what I came up with so far:

Notes:

- I'm using rxjava2
- the `getMainStream()` function is there to simulate some interaction

Here a runnable version of the code:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    getMainStream()
        .doOnNext(__ -> showLoading())
        .flatMap(__ -> loginUser().toObservable())
        .flatMap(__ -> createUser().toObservable())
        .doOnNext(userId -> {
            hideLoading();
            System.out.println("userId: " + userId);
        })
        .subscribe();
}

public static Completable loginUser() {
    return Completable.create(new CompletableOnSubscribe() {
        @Override
        public void subscribe(final CompletableEmitter e) throws Exception {
            Thread.sleep(500);
            System.out.println("loginUser");
            e.onComplete();
        }
    });
}

public static Single<String> createUser() {
    return Single.<String>create(new SingleOnSubscribe<String>() {
        @Override
        public void subscribe(final SingleEmitter<String> e) throws Exception {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("createUser");
            e.onSuccess("some_user_id");
        }
    });
}

public static Completable getCompletable(final String input) {
    return Completable.create(new CompletableOnSubscribe() {
        @Override
        public void subscribe(final CompletableEmitter e) throws Exception {
            Thread.sleep(750);
            System.out.println("completable, input=" + input);
            e.onComplete();
        }
    });
}

public static Observable<Object> getMainStream() {
    return Observable.just(new Object());
}

private static void hideLoading() {
    System.out.println("hideLoading()");
}

private static void showLoading() {
    System.out.println("showLoading()");
}
```

The console output of this is:

```
showLoading()
loginUser
```

Unfortunately, the login user never returns?!

I'm really looking forward to any help on this topic!

Thanks!!!

Comment: Don't think you need the huge intro. If the `loginUser` completes, it will not emit any value down the stream chain. But the `flatMap(__ -> createUser().toObservable())` will execute the `createUser` only when there is a new emitted object. Which means your whole chain will simply terminate.

Comment: why not? after all it calls complete and I thought `Completable` is just a special case of an `Observable`?! I tried the same chain swapping the `Completable` with a "real" `Observable` and then it works. I don't understand the benefit of having `Completable` and `Single` then if it's not chain able. #confused

Comment: Why both `Completable` and `Single` need to exist is a completely different question. You can actually cover every case with just an `Observable`. But, think 2 cases inserting something in your Database and making an Api request. The first one usually completes or returns error and the second one will usually return one item or error.

Comment: But it's very confusing if you cannot use them in conjunction with `Observables`. I did a lot of thinking when I came up with my solution and using a `Completable` for the first task and a `Single` for the second makes perfect sense. At first I only need to know when the action is completed so that I can continue and then I just need one value. But now I need to change the code to use `Observables` even though they are less appropriate for the job at hand... :(

Comment: You are right individually it makes perfect sense. But together? Your stream starts by emitting just one value. Then it executes a side effect `showLoading` which is not important. Then executes an action which doesn't return anything(looks to me like another case of side effect) and logically your stream will terminate(complete|error). Anyway you don't have to change much. Check `Completable.toSingleDefault` or `Completable.toSingle`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`loginUser()` is a `Completable` and when you convert the `Completable` to `Observable`, the effect is that the observable will complete. Hence, there is no downstream values to be acted upon by `createUser()`.

You might consider changing the expression to `loginUser().andThen( () -> createUser().toObservable()`, which results in emitting the string.

Comment: Let me try to understand this. A `Completable` is a special form of an `Observable` which never calls `onNext()` only `onComplete()` and therefore if chained together "doesn't allow" the stream to continue as the Stream only continues when `onNext()` is called. A `Single` on the other hand is chainable as it calls `onNext()` exactly once. Is that phrased correctly? Your suggested solution works btw. I ended up with `.flatMap(__ -> loginUser().andThen(createUser()).toObservable())`. Is that ok and not a misuse of the `flatMap()`

Comment: Your summary is correct. And `flatMap()` is intended for the purpose you put it to.